# Why do Domino store all my inline images in the xsppers folder?

Tags: xpages, inline-images

Every time I reload my webpage new files are added to the c:\windows\temp\notes...\xsppers folder on the server. and these files are never deleted, I have to manually delete them, and it can be several GB of data to delete every month

I have a simple xpage with a repeat control that display data from several documents using a computed Field mapped to a rich text field.

the richtext fields contain a lot of inline images that has been added using the notes client.

Now, every time I reload my webpage these images are now detached to the xspper folder and is causing my harddrive to run out of disc space all the time.

**What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I avoid it from happening?**

In the image below you see all the gifs that has been created with a new uinque name, each time I reload my webpage a new set up images are added to the folder.

I am using Domino 9

[image]

Comment: Does your server runs as service? If so, has that identity it runs under proper delete right for that folder?

Comment: Yes, It is run as a windows service. I see no reason why the images are added to the server file system at all.

Comment: This is likely to be down to the Persistence setting of your server or application

Comment: Paul, I just disabled the persistant settings in server doc and restarted the http task, In the application xsp I have set it to "keep pages in memory" still, the files are added to the server folder

Comment: if the files are only stored once on the server I can see benefits, but new files are added everytime I reload the same page/documents

Comment: Random guess, but since your images are inline, Domino will have to convert them to a format supported by web. This brings another question though, do you store your data as MIME in the rich text field?

Comment: Images are stored as RT. and it is the same behaviour if I add inline images from the web.

Comment: Do you have option "Store contents as HTML and MIME" enabled for rich text field?

Answer (score 1):

As Egor Margineanu wrote, this can happen if your images are *not* stored as MIME images in your Rich Text item.

This forces the domino server to detach the attachment(s) over and over again to disc, because it is required to generate a GIF form the inline image. If you change the MIME type of your rich text item in your form and save the document(s) again, the images are stored in the "correct" format, and the domino server is able to identify that the images are already on the HDD.

As far I can see the temorarly detached attachments are not wiped when the session ends. This seems to happen if the application ends.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but some clarification from the XPages Portable Command Guide, page 36:

> The files remain in the temporary persistence location until the user
> session expires. The file is not removed after the document is saved,
> although it is no longer referenced by URLs.
>
> It may be useful to change this
> setting to point to a different location if the folder is taking up
> too much space on the main server drive and another drive has more
> available space. This option is server-wide, so it should be set in
> the server xsp.properties file. Values set in a particular
> application’s xsp.properties file are ignored.

Based on your question, Thomas, it seems that this is not what you are experiencing.

Comment: Good info but unfortunately not an answer. This problem is really rediculous. I have a document with 8 inline images. every time this document is loaded in webbrowser 8 images are saved to server disc.

Comment: I understand. And they are not removed when the session expires?

Comment: how can I tell when a session expire?

Comment: The user is logged out when the session expires.

Comment: my users are never logged in, it is a public blog